# OpenTelemetry Collector in EKS cluster refuses connection with New Relic

Tags: amazon-eks, newrelic, open-telemetry

## **Scenario**

I'm attempting to use the OpenTelemetry Collector to send logs to New Relic. I've configured the collector according to the docs below, but I when I deploy the ConfigMap and Deployment listed below, I am receiving an error inside the Pod:

```
2022-08-09T17:30:27.347Z    info    service/collector.go:128    Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
2022-08-09T17:30:27.347Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] [Server #7 ListenSocket #8] ListenSocket created {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.345Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel picks a new address "otlp.nr-data.net:4317" to connect {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.347Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0xc0009d1fd0, {CONNECTING <nil>}  {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.347Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] [Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING   {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.363Z    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:191  [core] [Channel #5 SubChannel #6] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {
  "Addr": "otlp.nr-data.net:4317",
  "ServerName": "otlp.nr-data.net:4317",
  "Attributes": null,
  "BalancerAttributes": null,
  "Type": 0,
  "Metadata": null
}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 162.247.241.110:4317: connect: connection refused"    {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.363Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] [Channel #5 SubChannel #6] Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE   {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.363Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0xc000af71c0, {TRANSIENT_FAILURE connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 162.247.241.110:4317: connect: connection refused"}    {"grpc_log": true}
2022-08-09T17:30:27.363Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:174  [core] [Channel #5] Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE    {"grpc_log": true}
```

- [basic configs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/more-integrations/open-source-telemetry-integrations/opentelemetry/collector/opentelemetry-collector-basic/)
- [endpoint, port, and protocol](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/more-integrations/open-source-telemetry-integrations/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-setup/#review-settings)

## **Thoughts and Code**

I have attempted to use https, on port 4318, and both grpc and https on 443. I've also temporarily opened the egress in both my security groups and firewall for all protocols and traffic. Nothing appears to make a difference. For reference, I'm going to actually provide my manifests here, to start with. Apologies for the lengthy post.

#### ConfigMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: otel-collector-configmap
  namespace: observability
data:
  collector.yaml: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols: 
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:
      batch:
        send_batch_size: 5000
        timeout: 10s
    exporters:
      otlp:
        endpoint: "https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317"
        headers:
          "api-key": $NEW_RELIC_API_KEY
    service:
      telemetry:
        logs:
          level: "debug"
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp]
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp]
        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp]
```

#### Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: otel-collector-deployment
  namespace: observability
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: otel-collector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: otel-collector
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: otel-collector
          args:
            - --config=/conf/collector.yaml
          image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.57.2
          env:
            - name: NEW_RELIC_API_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: newrelic-secret
                  key: api-key
                  optional: false
          volumeMounts:
            - name: otel-collector-configmap
              mountPath: /conf
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
      volumes:
        - name: otel-collector-configmap
          configMap:
            name: otel-collector-configmap 
            items:
              - key: collector.yaml
                path: collector.yaml
```

## **Question**

Straightforwardly, can anyone see anything wrong? I've been debugging for two days now, and haven't found anything. How can I get the OpenTelemetry Collector to establish a connection with New Relic at the endpoint they provide? Has anyone encountered this error before? Have I typo'd in the manifests above, or missed something?

Comment: Do you have TCP connectivity to `otlp.nr-data.net:4317` from your cluster?

Comment: @JanGaraj I can exec into a Pod in the same namespace and `wget` it. Returns a 404, because the endpoint isn't expecting a GET like that, but that shows me that the request isn't being blocked by anything, right? 
---
`$ wget https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317
Connecting to otlp.nr-data.net:4317 (162.247.241.110:4317)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: For what it's worth, here is another check that passed:
**call**: `$ nc -z -v otlp.nr-data.net 4317`
**response**:`otlp.nr-data.net (162.247.241.110:4317) open`

Comment: Try to enable debug logs `telemetry.logs.level: debug`. For some reason TCP connection is failing. Try update to latest release `otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.57.2`.

Comment: @JanGaraj - Good thinking on the log level and version update. I updated the question above with the details, but still didn't see anything that made sense to me.

Comment: Try `Privileged` mode for OTEL pod. Maybe some security feature is a problem.

Comment: I attempted this, but it didn't appear to make any difference (same error).

Comment: In what part of the world are you? IIRC I ran initially into the same error and then changed to `https://otlp.eu01.nr-data.net:4317` which worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay here. I'm in the US. Their docs say to use the endpoint for over here. For regulatory/compliance reasons I would actually have to keep it here.